# XHR requests are cancelled in Cypress

Tags: cypress

My test in Cypress does the following:

1. Do the login
2. On the next page clicks a button
3. The button clicked in step 2, Cypress starts to load the correct URL but then the landing page (login screen from step 1) is displayed.
   I want that after clicking the button, Cypress waits for the page to load completely instead of returning to the login page.

I already tried `cy.wait()`, `"pageLoadTimeout": 900000,, "includeShadowDom": true, "modifyObstructiveCode":false, "responseTimeout": 120000`

This is what I got

[image]

Update: When I do `cy.intercept('myurl/#').as('get#') cy.get('button').click()// after clicking on this button the page should loads completely cy.wait('#get')` I got the following

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It seems you want to wait until routes resolve. If that is the case, you need to explicitly tell Cypress to do just that.

For example, if I want Cypress to wait for a specific route, I write it like so:

```javascript
cy.intercept('http://example.com/route').as('getRoute');
cy.wait('@getRoute'); // once the route resolves, cy.wait will resolve as well
```

Or similar example with `cy.route()` and multiple routes:

```javascript
cy.server();
cy.route('GET', '/api/route1').as('route1');
cy.route('GET', '/api/route2').as('route2');
cy.route('GET', '/api/route3').as('route3');

cy.get('button').click();

// again cy.wait() will resolve when all these routes resolve
cy.wait(['@route1', '@route2', 'route3']);
```

You can use `cy.route()` or `cy.intercept()`, the latter being a newer command with some differences you can read up on [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#Comparison-to-cy-route).

Syntax and usage for `cy.wait()` could be found [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Alias), there're also similar examples with waiting for routes.

Comment: tks @pavelsaman. I see cy.route() and cy.serve are() are out to date, so I tried: cy.intercept('myurl/#').as('get#') // The URL I want cypress waits to load, ends with '#'. cy.get('buton').click() //after clicking this button the page needs to be loaded completely cy.wait('@get#'), but the same behaviour is still happening (it starts to load the right URL and returns to landing page). Please see my updated question using cy.intercept and the picture of the result.

Comment: Fragment identifiers (that part after the first `#`) are not sent in HTTP requests to the server. They are only used within browsers on the client side so that browsers can do fancy stuff with them like automatically scroll to a certain part of a page. Therefore awaiting a url with a fragment identifier will always time out.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation. Understand the fragment identifiers. So I used another URL (took from DEV tools and named routes, that is: 'myurl.com/gw-pos/api/track/routes'). Based on this URL, I switched the code to ```cy.intercept('myurl.com/gwos/api/track/routes').as('getRoutes') cy.get('button').click() cy.wait('@getRoutes')```, but this also times out: 'No request ever occurred'

Comment: In general, your code is not wrong, but I'm like a blind person here when I can't try it out. Use browser's DevTools to find out what's going on on the site, you need to understand it before writing checks. Are you sure it's `gwos`? In your screenshots it's always `gw-os`. Use minimatch or regex in `cy.intercept()` and work the other way round, i.e. first you make it general, so it passes easily, and then you make the url more concrete to match exactly this route.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue on chrome browser. Some the XHR request is getting cancelled due to which my expected page is not loading.
Refer :[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73496431/cypress-cancelling-xhr-request-on-chrome-browser